# NatTable: Dynamically Changing Filter Row Combo Filter Based on Previous Selection

Tags: eclipse, nattable, nebula

I am working with NatTable in my Java application, and I have a specific requirement related to the filter row and combo filters. In my NatTable, I have a filter row with combo box filters, and I would like to dynamically change the options available in one combo box based on the selection made in a previous combo box in the same row.

For example, if the user selects an option in the first combo box, I want to update the options available in the second combo box in the same row dynamically.

I am currently using `EditConfigAttributes.CELL_EDITOR` to handle cell combo values. However, I'm unsure about the best way to dynamically update the options of the combo box based on the selection in a previous combo box.

Could someone provide guidance or an example code snippet on how to achieve this in NatTable? Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

```java
Collections.sort(EZPDContants.STATUS_LIST);
ComboBoxCellEditor comboBoxCellEditor = new ComboBoxCellEditor(MyContants.STATUS_LIST);
configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(EditConfigAttributes.CELL_EDITOR, comboBoxCellEditor, DisplayMode.NORMAL,
        FilterRowDataLayer.FILTER_ROW_COLUMN_LABEL_PREFIX + 0);

Collections.sort(EZPDContants.SOP_LIST);
ComboBoxCellEditor attributeValue = new ComboBoxCellEditor(MyContants.SOP_LIST);
configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(EditConfigAttributes.CELL_EDITOR, attributeValue, DisplayMode.NORMAL,
        FilterRowDataLayer.FILTER_ROW_COLUMN_LABEL_PREFIX + 1);
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing a fixed list you can create the `ComboBoxCellEditor` with a `IComboBoxDataProvider`. That one somehow needs to know the context to determine which values to return.

See https://eclipse.dev/nattable/documentation.php?page=faq for an example.

Comment: "In my NatTable view with pagination, I'm facing an issue when applying filters. Let's say the first page contains 1000 data items, and the second page contains 2000. If I apply a filter on the second page, the displayed data is reduced to 1000. However, when I navigate back to the first page from the second page and clear the filter using FilterList.clear(), it only clears the 1000 data from the filter, leaving the remaining 1000 unaffected. I want to ensure that clearing the filter removes all data from the FilterList. How can I achieve this behavior?"

Comment: NatTable does not provide a pagination feature. As the question is dependent on your custom implementation of such a feature that is not known to anybody, I assume no one can answer the additional unrelated question to the initial question.

Answer (score 0):

In my implementation of `IComboBoxDataProvider#getValues`, I've successfully achieved dynamic filter changes. I'm utilizing a `FilterList<MyData>` within the method to extract distinct values based on the provided column index. The following code snippet illustrates this approach:

```java
    @Override
    public List<?> getValues(int columnIndex, int rowIndex) {
        // Assuming you have a FilterList<MyData> named filterList
        FilterList<MyData> filterList = ...;
    
        // Ensure filterList is not null
        if (filterList == null) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
    
        // Dynamically provide distinct values for the specified column
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                // Extract distinct values from the specified column using Java streams
                return filterList.stream()
                    .map(MyData::getOk)
                    .distinct()
                    .sorted()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            default:
                break;
        }
    
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
```